# I am looking for a tool that allows me to post to Instagram from python

Tags: python, cron, bots, instagram, scheduler

I am looking for a tool that allows me to post to Instagram from python.

I would like to automate the process using a scheduler like Heroku or GCP cloud scheduler, so we think that something like selenium that uses GUI is not really suitable.
(It may be possible to run it with selenium, though.)

I already tried instapy-cli and instabot, but they seemed to be unavailable now.

https://github.com/b3nab/instapy-cli

https://instagrambot.github.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code from [Automating Instagram Posts with Python and Instagram Graph API](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/automating-instagram-posts-with-python-and-instagram-graph-api-374f084b9f2b).

```
import requests
import config
import json
```

```
def postInstagramQuote():
#Post the Image
    image_location_1 = 'http:path-to-your-image.com/img/image-name.jpg'
    post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/{}/media'.format(config.ig_user_id)
payload = {
    'image_url': image_location_1,
    'caption': 'Get jobs online on https://careers-portal.co.za #career #hiring #jobs #job #jobssouthafrica #hiringnow,
    'access_token': config.user_access_token
    }
    r = requests.post(post_url, data=payload)
    print(r.text)
result = json.loads(r.text)
    if 'id' in result:
        creation_id = result['id']
second_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/{}/media_publish'.format(config.ig_user_id)
        second_payload = {
        'creation_id': creation_id,
        'access_token': config.user_access_token
        }
        r = requests.post(second_url, data=second_payload)
        print('--------Just posted to instagram--------')
        print(r.text)
    else:
        print('HOUSTON we have a problem')
postInstagramQuote()
```

REMINDER: You can only post from an Instagram business account, and not to your personal Instagram account.

Comment: Your answer helped me to successfully accomplish what I wanted to do! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can try [the official Instagram API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-) for which you are going to have to set up a [business account](https://help.instagram.com/502981923235522?fbclid=IwAR1P3QEgKcrUNkc4NWS4ofCgyhGz3xxwvLbZHUCuOSEVNljmjJCihb01Cec).

Comment: Your answer helped me to successfully accomplish what I wanted to do! Thank you so much!